# A space between footer and image

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

On Apple `IMAC` 27" and other big screens
I'm having an issue with footer. `www.ewafest.com` (website)

The image has

```
 .ewkaimg {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0%;
    right:0%;
}
```

I want the image to stick to the footer that is why.
And the footer should be always on the bottom of the website without this weird space ( not sticky ).

[Weird space between a footer and the bottom of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbgHf.png)

I'm down to learning some `Jquery` so if you guys can recommend something that would be awesome.
And feel free to blast me if i posted the question wrong.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need:

1. Make `background-size: 100% 100%;` on `<body>` tag (cause now the background is bigger than the `<body>` tag itself.
2. Change `height` of `<div class="et_slide_in_menu_container">` from `100%` to `auto` (because of the same reason)

Comment: I did it and the space is still there :(

Comment: There must be some misunderstanding. What do you want your page look like? Should footer be located at the very bottom of the screen?

Comment: Exactly no matter the screen size I am sorry maybe my english is a problem.

Comment: Just checked the website `www.ewafest.com/`. There is no space below footer anymore, have you figured out what was wrong?

Comment: Yes i did i have a problem with woman on the right now. I cant stick her to the footer.

Answer (score -2):

use custom CSS:

```
#footer-bottom{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's staying glued to the screen can i somehow just make it stay on the bottom ?

Comment: Yes i did and it glued the footer to the screen, when i scrolled the footer were moving too.

Comment: You may do `position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%;` on `<article>` tag.